# How can I get this d3 tree chart to work locally?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to learn to work with d3 and make something similar to this collapsible tree:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

What can I do to make this interactive tree chart work locally?

I have saved the following files from the web all in the same directory:

```
   d3_graph/tree_files/tree.html
   d3_graph/tree_files/d3.js
   d3_graph/tree_files/d3.layout.js
   d3_graph/tree_files/flare.json
   d3_graph/tree_files/style.css
```

This produced the graph, but it looks like chrome saved an already drawn SVG created by the javascript in tree.html, and the tree is not interactive like in the link above.

After looking at the source of the working version on the web, I saw the code was different, so I pasted that in to tree.html and changed the file to point at the correct locations of d3.js, d3.layout.js, style.css and flare.json

This still produced a blank white page and I'm not sure what else to do. How can I make this work?

Here is my edited version of tree.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.layout.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">


.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font-size: 11px;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>



</body></html>
```

EDIT:
I just checked the console in chrome to find this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/user/Downloads/d3_graph/tree_files/flare.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Could it be that I can't run this locally and need to access tree.html through a web server?

Answer (score 1):

the other answers work, but there is an alternative if you don't want to fire a web server:

- Firefox should open your file and load the local json by default, so nothing to do there.
- you can launch Chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`, and the JSON will be loaded.

Comment: I also would encourage avoiding a local server and just opening it in mozilla or google chrome. Like @mef says, if you open the `.html` in either of those browsers, it should display it as if it were a webpage hosted locally. Also, don't use IE, the svg rendering in it is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The .json file needed to be loaded through an http request, so placing the files on a web server and accessing tree.html though `http://myserver/tree.html` fixes this problem.

Comment: I'm not using a local/web server and I'm able to load locally JSON files with no problem... What I _think_ actually happens is: if you use a local/web HTTP server for your HTML document, you _have_ to load the JSON via HTTP request. If you are using a static HTML file with the script, loading _local_ JSON files also works as long as you have stored `d3.js` locally as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using d3. Likely the file wouldn't load because some browsers have restrictions that prevent them from loading local files via JavaScript (for security).
I know you've answered your question, but for completeness, you can also use your own local computer to host and serve the files to yourself.

- Open Terminal
- Navigate to the file directory you're working with
  (using `cd`, if your files are on your Desktop in a folder called
  project: `cd Desktop/project`)
- Use Python to run a server:
  type`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234 &.`  The numbers are the port, you can use any four digits you like.
- Go to your browser and type
  `localhost:1234`
- `localhost:1234/page2.html` for other files