# D3 map saved locally showing two or more times on web page

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, svg, d3.js

Hello I am trying to display a map using D3. I have saved some D3 demo webpages locally in order to study them. Iam confronted with a problem which I cannot understand: the locally saved webpages display maps which are displayed at least twice, none of which however works as it should.

Examples of the pages in question are as follows:
http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/
http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/

What is the difference between the onnline and offline versions?

I have googled this issue without success. I have not enough experience with svg to deep troubleshoot myself. Can somebody please help me? Than you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? How are you saving and running the pages locally and how do the maps show up twice? At least the former example runs perfectly fine locally for me.

Comment: I am using firefox and I am saving complete pages - from File>Save page as and setting "Complete web page" in save as dropdown box.

Comment: Should work. You can also get the former example from [github](https://github.com/larskotthoff/v-igdp).

Comment: Ok thank you. Your suggestion coupled with @VividD is halping me understand how D3 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to tell you that I reproduced your problem: I did "Save As..." (with option Complete Page) in Chrome for http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/, and I got area for the map twice, actually the map is not displayed in first area correctly.

Now, I will probably confuse you with following sentences, but try to follow them... :) The thing is that D3 works in such way that it usually adds various elements of html pages while the page is loaded. Initial html page usually has just few elements, if any. Thats the way D3 is designed to work. This also means that when you press "Save As...", your html file will contain such D3-generated elements. And then, when you load such saved page in your browser, D3 will again add one more set of these elements, and you will end up having two sets of elements. And, of course, something might happen along this way that might confuse D3, and nothing will work - since D3 expect almost empty html page.

The problem is that you assumed that "Save As..." works for D3-powered web pages, however, it is simply not the case...

However, there is a workaround: You can delete html elements that are previously generated by D3. In this case, this code is on line 213, it a huge line - delete all that is under svg tag. I believe after that only closing script tag should remain in that line.

Another problem are json files, that are usually not saved with your page. So, in this case, aou need to manually save http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/countries.geojson in the same location as you saved original page.

Also, you need to run all this in "server environment", this usually means that you need to go with terminal to the dir in question, and type "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8082", and than use "localhost:8082" as your root dir that you type in the browser address bar. Maybe you are already familiar with this, and also you can find better explanations on the web
for running simple HTTP server.

I do successfully use site from larsko.org that I saved locally, after applying all steps that I described.

Hopefully this would help you.

EDIT: I tried the second site, too, with similar procedure. After "Save As..." I got two mall maps, instead of one. In order to get the correct site, I just needed to replace huge line 201 from html file with this line:

```
<figure><div id="mall-map" style="width: 720px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177709/how-can-i-get-this-d3-tree-chart-to-work-locally?rq=1 you can find another explanation about need to run http server and command "python -m ..."

Comment: All of the visualisations on my site are also on github. Cloning the repository will avoid issues like this.

Comment: Agreed. However, it looks to me that it is reasonable for user to expect that browser's "Save Page As..." produces fairly similar copy of a particular web page. That's why I believe that this is a legitimate question and, even further, that browsers could do a better job regarding saving pages.

Comment: I agree with @VividD that "Save As" is expected to save the current state of the page, not the original html.  While it is easy to say that the browsers shouldn't run the initialization routine a second time when loading the saved page, there isn't any way for the browser to know which scripts should be re-run or not.  It's not something I'd thought of before, but it would be good coding practice, when writing a routine that expects to start from an empty div or svg element, to add in an `.html("")` after your initial select statement, to make sure you're working on a blank slate.